# Fatal error: Class 'view' not found

Tags: views

I've tried to create a new View Filter with a module. After the upload and activation of my module, I got a White Screen. So I decided to deactivate and delte my module again. Now I'm stuck with this message everywhere:

```
Fatal error: Class 'view' not found in /var/www/cosmicdesign.at/www/html/antiquariat/sites/all/modules/views/views.module on line 1604
```

I tried to deactivate views, but that don't do anything. Also cleared the cache in the db (as I can't access the backend). Anyone got a solution to bring the site up and running again?